# How to enter query-replace-regexp with key binding C-M-%, if emacs session is not stand-alone but in mate-terminal running Bash?

Tags: terminal-emacs, bash, query-replace, query-replace-regexp

Title says it all. The problem: When you start emacs within a terminal running a shell, Meta and Ctrl key act in strange ways: In some regards they work, in others, however, not as it used to be coming from emacs stand-alone usage. The solution: Enter Meta and Ctrl differently.
Example: mark-sexp - set mark ARG sexps from point; the place mark goes is the same place C-M-f would move to with the same argument.

`[cursor]The weather is so nice.`

C-M-SPC

`[cursor][mark]The[/mark] weather is so nice.`

In stand-alone emacs sessions, you would type Ctrl-[Alt/Meta]-SPC and it happens.

In emacs sessions within mate-terminal running Bash, however, typing in works differently:

Holding Ctrl, additionally typing [ - replacing Alt/Meta, being alternative way to enter Alt/Meta - and then either holding it or releasing it and typing in Ctrl-SPC.

And now the big quiz question:
How to do that with C-M-%?

You see, this key binding is very similar to the example; the only notable difference: That 3rd key, in this case %, it seems to require holding shift while typing "5" for "%" to appear, but that's probably where emacs sessions within mate-terminal running Bash don't play along.
My suspicion - and it can be wrong: Whenever C-M-[3rd key] doesn't need usage of the shift key, described alternative way works, but whenever that 3rd key makes usage of the shift key necessary, it doesn't work - not just with 3rd key being %, but all others requiring shift key usage.

Trying it, typing Crtl-[, holding or releasing it, and then Ctrl-Shift-5, invokes Query-replace, as if just [Alt/Meta]-Shift-5 was typed in within the emacs session in mate-terminal running Bash, but not query-replace-regexp, as desired.

The bad consequence: Imagine you have a text with several number sets containing seperator `.` - example 843.87921, 2.99, and so on - and you want to replace the `.` with another separator, `,` for example - 843,87921, 2,99 - you can do that in one go with query-replace-regexp using grouping, and back-referencing to the number sequences before and after the separator within the replace-string - \1,\2 - well, but if you can't invoke query-replace-regexp, but just the simple, normal query-replace, that won't work. It needs a tool being capable of handling grouping and back-referencing.

Is there any default way of typing in C-M-% differently, which makes invocation of query-replace-regexp work within emacs sessions in mate-terminal running Bash?

I am aware that giving up on the more efficient key binding entry and instead going the less efficient X way (eXtend) by typing in M-x, followed by writing "query-replace-regexp" is an option.

I'm using emacs version:
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2017-09-20 on lcy01-07, modified by Debian

My free/libre OS is Trisquel.

Comment: Didn't read the whole thing but have you tried `ESC C-%`? Before the meta key was invented, `M-anything` was typed `ESC anything` and that is still the case today.